# unable to create Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table a:

```
PROTOCOL      VARCHAR2(20)
```

Table b:

```
YEAR          NUMBER(4)
MONTH         VARCHAR2(20)
PROTOCOL      VARCHAR2(20)
DATE1         DATE
```

My procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE his
    @Year NUMBER(4),
    @Month VARCHAR2(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION trninsert
        DECLARE @@date DATE
        SET @@date = sysdate;
        INSERT INTO b (Year, month, date1, protocol)
        (select @Year, @Month, @@date,* from a)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION trninsert
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION trninsert
    END CATCH
END
```

I am using plsql developer and it is showing errors in procedure.

Comment: What errors it is showing?

Comment: Compilation errors for PROCEDURE CAFANALYST.HIS
#13#10Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:
       
          ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order using compiled
          wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined
Line: 2
Text: @Year number(4),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've written this a mysql type syntax.

oracle would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE his(p_year  b.year%type,
                     p_month b.month%type)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO b (Year, month, date1, protocol)
  select p_year, p_month, sysdate, a.protocol
    from a;
  commit;
END;
```

though its bad form to commit in the procedure.

eg:

```
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE his(p_year  b.year%type,
  2                       p_month b.month%type)
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5    INSERT INTO b (Year, month, date1, protocol)
  6    select p_year, p_month, sysdate, a.protocol
  7      from a;
  8    commit;
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> insert into a values('prot a');

1 row created.

SQL> exec his(2012, 10)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from b;

      YEAR MONTH                PROTOCOL             DATE1
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------
      2012 10                   prot a               06-FEB-13

SQL>
```

Comment: Its working. I got the output.Thank you very much for your help. very much appreciated.

Comment: hi its working but i wanted to use the same for total 5 tables data. so instead of writing b.year%type,b.month%type, can we use generic parameters and create only one procedure with 5 insert into statements?

Comment: @user2039795 by generics you mean `varchar2` etc instead of `%type`? if so, sure.

Comment: i tried but it is showing error like "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:       
          := . ) , @ % default character
       The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
.....code i used is create OR REPLACE procedure HISTORY1
(h_Year number(4),
h_month varchar2(15))
as
begin

Comment: @user2039795 you cannot specify precision on the inputs. `(h_Year number, h_month varchar2)` only.

Comment: Thank you. its working. i will implement  the same for all history tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is not in a valid format: Change your entire structure with,

```
  CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```

For more parameters: Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm)

Answer (score 0):

yeah you have not use the plsql syntax:

Code will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE his
    (Year b.year%type,
    Month b.month%type)
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO b (Year, month, date1, protocol)
        VALUES select Year, Month, sysdate,a.protocol from a ;
COMMIT;

END;
```